# a question about polynomial funcions and natural basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Question form Greub's book Linear Algebra

[image]

Construct a natural basis? Isn't enough to say that $1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n,\dots$ is a basis and then show that?

Comment: This is the "natural" basis often called the "canonical basis".

Comment: Natural, because the basis vectors are evident in the very definition of vectors. Generator, that's pretty obvious. For linear independence, you can use that a polynomial function that vanishes into an infinity of real numbers is zero so all the coefficients are zero.

Comment: @Peter. This is ok, but when the author wrote "construct a natural basis", I understand that there is a method to construct the basis. I would say that $1,x,x^2,\dots$ is the natural basis, but I don't see any construction here.

Comment: @spohreis I agree that the word "construct" doesn't really fit the solution. Nevertheless, I think that $1,x,x^2,\dots$ is indeed the solution that the author had in mind.